# Solving the system of equation with the expression of total differentiation using Cramer's rule

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to solve the following system of equations of total differentiation using Cramer's rule.

[image]

And I got the following message:

[image]

where `d` is delta as the symbol of differentiation. Eventually I want to evaluate the signs of $\frac{du^H}{d\pi^H}$ and $\frac{du^L}{d\pi^H}$. Please help.

```
A = {{-1 + Cross[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]^H, Pi^H] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^H,
  Cross[k, \[Phi] + Cross[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]^L, Pi^L] + 
  Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^L], 0}, {Cross[1 - Pi^L, z/k], -Pi,
  Cross[1 - Pi^L, u^H/k]}, {-Cross[1 - \[Zeta]^H, Subscript[q, u]^H],
  Cross[1 - \[Zeta]^L, Subscript[q, u]^L], 0}};
v = {du^H, du^L, dz};
c = {Cross[Cross[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]^H, u^H], d\[Pi]^H] - 
  Cross[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]^L, d\[Pi]^L],  Cross[u^L +
  Cross[z/k, u^H], d\[Pi]^L], Cross[1 - \[Zeta]^H, Subscript[q, Pi]^H,
  d\[Pi]^H] - Cross[1 - \[Zeta]^L, Subscript[q, Pi]^L, d\[Pi]^L]};
A // MatrixForm
eqs = A . v;

eqs[ [1] ] == c[ [1] ]
eqs[ [2] ] == c[ [2] ]
eqs[ [3] ] == c[ [3] ]

Solve[{eqs[ [1] ] == c[ [1] ], eqs[ [2] ] == c[ [2] ], 
  eqs[ [3] ] == c[ [3] ]}, {du^H, du^L, dz}]
```

```
Solve::ivar: du^H is not a valid variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica you cannot use superscript input, they are interpreted as powers. Pi is reserved as the numerical symbol of $\pi$, differentials are

```
 D, Dt, Derivative
```

Even the use of subscripted variables causes difficulties  since unknowns in equation should be simple symbols.

You can transform the sub- and superscripted variables

```
 ( A /. {Subscript[x_, p_] :> Symbol[StringJoin[ToString /@ {x, p}]]})/. 
    {Power[x_ ,  p_Symbol] :> Symbol[StringJoin[ToString /@ {x, p}]]} 

{{-1+\[Alpha]2H+\[Alpha]1H\[Cross]PiH,k\[Cross](\[Alpha]2L+
\[Phi]+\[Alpha]1L\[Cross]PiL),0},
{(1-PiL)\[Cross](z/k),-\[Pi],(1-PiL)\[Cross](uH/k)},
{-(1-\[Zeta]H)\[Cross]quH,(1-\[Zeta]L)\[Cross]quL,0}}
```

but be careful for linear terms of Symbols like $\pi^1=\\Pi$ which have to dealt with by hand.